# javascript if Statement with Boolean Not Working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I have a mouseover and mouseenter function that should only work if my variable is not set to true. But the mouse functions fire no matter what.

The If Statement checks to see if a variable is NOT TRUE but it doesn't seem to be working as I have it setup. The click function sets the variable to true, so when it is clicked, I should not be able to see the mouseover function working, until I set 'executed' back to false.

Any guidance is appreciated

```
var executed = false;

if (executed != true) {
    $('.elm').mouseover(function(event) {
        // do something only if variable is not set to true
    })
};
if (executed != true) {
    $('.elm').mouseout(function(event) {
        // do something only if variable is not set to true
    })
};

$('.elm').click(function() {
    // do something and set variable to true
    executed = true;

});
```

Comment: you are setting stuff to do only if some condition is false. Try to do something like  $('.elm').mouseout(function(event) {
if (executed != true) {
 // do something only if variable is not set to true
do you logic here 
}
})

Comment: first of all, just check if(!executed) instead of != true, second you should add if statement inside mouseOver listener function

Comment: By the time you click and set the variable to true the mouseover and mouseout events are already registered because the intial value of your variable was false.

Comment: You are *binding the event handler* if `executed != true`. Which it always is. You will want to check *within the event handler at the time of the event* whether you want to do something or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statements only determine whether the `mouseover` / `mouseout` event handlers are registered. They are, because `false` is ... well, not true.

Later on, the value of `executed` changes, but it doesn't matter anymore because those `if` statements are not executed again. The event handlers are already registered and get called.

You probably want to do this instead:

```
$('.elm').mouseover(function(event) {
  if (executed != true) {
    // do something only if variable is not set to true
  }
});
```

I.e. always register the callback, but check the `executed` variable *inside* the function, every time it is called.

You can simplify this logic a bit:

```
$('.elm').mouseover(function(event) {
  if (executed) {
    return;
  }
  // do something only if variable is not set to true
});
```

Just return early if `executed` is true. This way you don't have to wrap the whole function body in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Disable the events itself

```
$('.elm').click(function() {
  // do something and set variable to true
  disableMouseEvents();
  executed = true;

});

function disableMouseEvents(){
   let el = $('.elm');
   // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
   if ( el.removeEventListener ){
      el.removeEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
   }
   // For IE 8 and earlier versions
   else if(el.detachEvents){
      el.detachEvent("mouseout", myFunction);
   }
}
```

Then to enable your event listener. Just add them back where you set your executed flag to be true.